# Retrieve datas from an old Lacie RAID0 / JBOD array

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount, raid

I've had like 10 years ago a Lacie external USB 1TB hard drive. One day it stopped working properly and it turns out that the internal electronic was gone. Inside it I found two identical 500GB samsung disks (s.m.a.r.t. tests on both disks were OK) that I used to mount as an external storage to retrieve my datas, but nothing were found inside... so I guessed the Lacie device was mounting the two drives as a RAID0 to optimize speed, but it could also be a JBOD array.

I still have the two disks and never used them. Do you think it's possible to mount them in my HP microserver n40l NAS and get some data back with TrueNAS?

Any other suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I would look for a used drive of the same model just to get the enclosure, and replace the disks with your old disks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It's pretty hard to find that disk these days... it was a LAC301301E (first release 2007?). I had no luck on used electronic sites.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comment find working Lacie unit and place the disks there. Do not forget to mark the places of HDD and to put them in new unit on the same way. If you are lucky you will get your information. If one of the disks is out you are also out of luck. You see one disk (1TB) which mean RAID0. So with only one disk from the array you can't restore the information. in RAID0 the information is splitted between two disks (with size of chunk, usually 128kb).

Comment: It's pretty hard to find that old (2007?) device still being sold on used electronics stores online... at least i've had no luck till now.
Anyway i've found out that it's not a RAID0, but a JBOD array... when i mount the first disk in the filesystem i see a part of the files (i can copy some, but some are null files). The second HD can't even be mounted on the FS...